# Android SSLHandshake failed - CA certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, handshake

I want to secure my SSL connection to the socket. But unfortunately, I have a problem with CA certificate.

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.unwrap(OpenSSLEngineImpl.java:441)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:1014)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper$5.onDataAvailable(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:194)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.Util.emitAllData(Util.java:23)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncNetworkSocket.onReadable(AsyncNetworkSocket.java:152)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:789)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:627)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$700(AsyncServer.java:41)
    at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$13.run(AsyncServer.java:569)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:337)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLEngineImpl.java:666)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake_bio(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.unwrap(OpenSSLEngineImpl.java:426)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

My code:

```
    String type = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(type);
    trustStore.load(null, null);
    trustStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", new CA().getCert());

    String tmfAlg = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlg);
    tmf.init(trustStore);

    try {
         SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
         context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
         SSLEngine engine = context.createSSLEngine();

         AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.handshake(socketNormal, url, port, engine, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new NoopHostnameVerifier(), true, (e, socket1) -> {
// ... more
```

My cert is in my assets catalog:

```
    public X509Certificate getCert() throws CertificateException, IOException {
        CertificateFactory certFactory;
        certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(context.getAssets().open("pem.pem"));
        return (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
    }
```

My certificate is signed using a private key and it is self-signed.

Obviously, it is working without cert... but it's not secure.

## EDIT:

I have tried to put existing BKS Keystore instead of dynamically adding at run-time:

```
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(c.getAssets().open("key.bks"));
    trustStore.load(is, "12345".toCharArray());
    Log.i("Cert", "ca " + (new CA().getCert()).getSubjectDN());

    String tmfAlg = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlg);
    tmf.init(trustStore);

    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        SSLEngine engine = context.createSSLEngine();

        AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.handshake(socketNormal, url, port,
        engine, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new NoopHostnameVerifier(), true, (e, socket1) -> {
```

But unfortunetly the error is the same.

EDIT 2:

More info:

- Server PHP generates this cert using:

  ```
  function createSSLCert($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $pem_dn) {
      // //create ssl cert for this scripts life.
      //Create private key
      $privkey = openssl_pkey_new();
      //Create and sign CSR
      $cert    = openssl_csr_new($pem_dn, $privkey);
      $cert    = openssl_csr_sign($cert, null, $privkey, 365 * 99);//365

      //Generate PEM file
      $pem = array();
      openssl_x509_export($cert, $pem[0]);
      openssl_pkey_export($privkey, $pem[1], $pem_passphrase);
      $pem = implode($pem);

      //Save PEM file
      //echo $pem;
      file_put_contents($pem_file, $pem);
      //chmod($pem_file, 0600);
  }


      $pem_passphrase = "XXXXX";   //Set a password here
      $pem_file = "cert.pem";    //Set a path/filename for the PEM SSL Certificate which will be created.
      //The following array of data is needed to generate the SSL Cert
      $pem_dn = array(
      "countryName" => "PL",                 //Set your country name
      "localityName" => "City",        //Ser your city name
      "organizationName" => "Firm name",  //Set your company name
      "commonName" => "CN",  //Set your full hostname.
      "emailAddress" => "admin@email.pl"  //Set your email address
      );

      //create ssl cert for this scripts life.
      $this->createSSLCert($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $pem_dn);
  ```
- Keystore was created using Portecle tool like:
  New -> BKS -> Import Trusted Certificate -> My *pem file -> save
- `openssl s_client -debug -connect 10.100.0.24:5678` return:

> No client certificate CA names sent
>       Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
>       ---
>       SSL handshake has read 1630 bytes and written 451 bytes
>       ---
>       New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
>       Server public key is 2048 bit
>       Secure Renegotiation IS supported
>       Compression: NONE
>       Expansion: NONE
>       No ALPN negotiated
>
> ```
> Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
> ```

plus some private informations about cert

Comment: What does `new CA().getCert()` do? Does it load an existing certificate or does it generate a new one?

Comment: @Robert It loads existing cert from assets (I posted body of `getCert()` method)

Comment: Have you tried to put the self-signed server certificate into a BKS keystore and put that in the asset dir and load it instead of dynamically adding it at run-time? Portecle is an easy UI tool for creating such a keystore.

Comment: @Robert Yes I did - same exception

Comment: I would try the trustmanager with the standard HttpsUrlConnection to see if AsyncSSLSocketWrapper causes the error. If not you imported the wrong certificate or not the complete chain.

Comment: @Robert Using standard SSLSocket connection return the same error. I will post more information about my cert ificate